# メソッドの呼び出しをインスタンス変数が nil の場合に行う時の引数のとり方

Tags: ruby

メソッドの呼び出しをインスタンス変数が初期化されてないときにだけ行う方法として

```
def foo
  @foo ||= foo_init
end
```

のような書き方がありますが、`foo`が引数を取る時はどのように書くのが良いでしょうか？
現状は

```
def initialize
  @foo = {}
end

def foo(arg)
  @foo[arg] ||= foo_init(arg)
end
```

または

```
def foo(arg)
  @foo = {} if foo.nil?
  @foo[arg] ||= foo_init(arg)
end
```

としていますがもっと良い書き方はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

あえて1行で書くなら下記のように書けます。

```
def foo(arg)
  (@foo ||= {})[arg] ||= foo_init(arg)
end
```

では、このコードがわかりやすいかと言われると、全くそうとは思えません。変な工夫はせずに、2行にした方が良いでしょう。

```
def foo(arg)
  @foo ||= {}
  @foo[arg] ||= foo_init(arg)
end
```

もうひとつは、`@foo`と直接インスタンス変数を見に行かずに、常にメソッド経由で取得するという物です。

```
def foo_hash
  @foo ||= {}
end

def foo(arg)
  foo_hash[arg] ||= foo_init(arg)
end
```

`foo_hash`呼び出しの度に`||=`の処理が入ることでちょっと遅くなりますので、頻繁に呼び出す場合は注意が必要です。ただ、速度を気にするのであれば、`initialize`で初期化しておいた方が良いでしょう。